# What word/expression do you use when you talk about employments in terms of work rate?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Employments may differ in terms of how much the employee is supposed to work – part time or full time, right? But how do you refer to this phenomenon? Do you talk about "the extent of the employment" or "the work rate of the employment" or... what?

I want to say

> The work rate of an adjunct position should be dictated by the requirements of the relevant institution.

but I'm not sure whether "work rate" is the correct word to use here, or whether it should be "extent" or something else entirely.

Comment: I think "employments" is enough for describing such stuff. You need not add additional words/phrases with it.

Comment: For "work rate" are you looking for [**productivity**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/productivity)? Or perhaps one asks "What are the/your hours?"

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh uh... huh? When you specify the details of an employment it's not really to just state that it's an employment, right? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @WeatherVane No... I want to describe a particular employment, and state the facts about it, as it were. As in a situation where you announce a vacancy and you specify what the "extent" (or whatever word you use) is – 25%; 50%; 75% or 100%. I know I'm bad at explaining what I'm after...

Comment: You give the **hours**, example "About 20 hours per week" or "Three days a week" or "Full time" etc. So you ask the employer "What are the hours?"

Comment: @WeatherVane This is what I need to say: "The work rate of an adjunct position should be dictated by the requirements of the relevant institution", but I'm not sure whether "work rate" is the correct word to use here, or whether it should be "extent" or something else entirely

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh The word "employments" is not idiomatic. Employment is a mass noun, denoting something that can't be counted.

Comment: "The requirements of the institution should dictate whether the work (or position) is part-time or full-time." Or "The working-hours are entirely up to the employer!"

Comment: @OldBrixtonianThank you!! Shall I take this as an indication that you don't really have a word for this in English? (Now I'm just curious – you suggestions are great as they are!)

Comment: The line between full- and part-time seems to be set around 35 hours per week. You might use "hours per week" or "weekly hours" to refer to the employed time. As a side note, I wonder whether you have a word for that in your native language?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you! And, in answer to your question: yes, we do :) I'm just baffled that you don't :)

Answer (score 2):

The term "work rate" does not fit here.  That generally refers to the rate at which work is completed, often in an assembly-line type of position.  For example:

"The worker's union filed a grievance with management over the continued increase in the work rate demanded of employees."

Some suggestions of what you might use in this case are:

"The **work schedule** of an adjunct position should be dictated by the requirements of the relevant institution."

"The **working hours** of an adjunct position should be dictated by the requirements of the relevant institution."

Comment: Thank you! Great suggestions!